# How can I keep track of a "role" in an organisation (eg. secretary) over time (1980-1995)

Tags: relationships, tags, roles

Under individual contacts, I want to keep track of roles over time within my organisation's executive committee. So, every couple of years the Secretary, Treasurer, Chair, London Rep, Wales Rep etc etc. are newly elected.

I want to be able to record on a contact that they were the secretary from 1999-2001 for example, and then they were the chair from 2001-2004. I expect a full date will be used, but for simplicity we would usually just include the year, as most elections will take place at the AGM and therefore the same month every year. There are of course exceptions, where people resign mid-term.

I would also like to be able to record that they were the "X" role from 2016-present, and be able to display/view all the "Current" roles, based on them being "X" month/year to "present".

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to CiviCRM StackExchange Daniel!

The CiviCRM relationships functionality will work perfectly for your use case scenario -

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/relationships

You can have different relationship types (roles) and they can be linked between individuals and organisations. A contact can also have multiple relationships.

And of course relationships include both a start and end date.

[image]